# Create control in thread and loading photo async

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, async-await

I have a Windows Form, inside I have a Button and a Panel.

On button click I'm adding a control to the panel... as many as I want. This process is using Task Factory. Example:

```
private void ButtonClick()
{
// This line needs to happen on the UI thread...
            TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

               CustomControl.PersonResult newControl = new CustomControl.PersonResult();
               this.panel1.Controls.Add(newControl);

            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
}
```

My PersonResult.cs control has the following layout:

[image]

The control has a picturebox and 3 lables.

Now, when a new **PersonResult** control is added to the form, I want to perform other background worker in order to get an image from the internet and place it in the picturebox.

So, the scenario is:

I press the button many times and immediately I will see the customcontrol added to the panel, but the picturebox of every control will be empty, but then images will start appearing as soon as the worker loads the image from internet and place it on the picturebox.

Any clue on how do implement this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `//This line happens in the UI thread...` and the rest too XD. You can't  manipulate the UI from a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you touch a control you must do so from the UI thread.  You can do the actual downloading of the picture and other long-running tasks from your thread/task.  From your thread you use Control.Invoke to invoke a delegate on the UI thread.

This MSDN article has a good example of using Control.Invoke with simple variables like strings and such:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.100).aspx

But often a helper class is used so you can pass more complex data between your delegates without resorting to big nasty object arrays.

Here's some sample code I did up:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                DataClass dataClass = new DataClass(this.textBox1);

                Thread.Sleep(5000); // simulate long running task

                dataClass.TextToPass = "set some text";
                dataClass.updateTargetControl();

            });
    }


    private class DataClass {
        delegate void updateTextBoxOnUiThreadDelegate();

        private TextBox _targetControl= null;
        private updateTextBoxOnUiThreadDelegate _updateDelegate; 




        internal DataClass(TextBox targetControl) {
            _updateDelegate = new updateTextBoxOnUiThreadDelegate(updateOnUiThread);
            _targetControl = targetControl;
        }

        internal string TextToPass = "";


        internal void updateTargetControl() {
            _targetControl.Invoke(_updateDelegate);
        }

        private void updateOnUiThread() {
            _targetControl.Text = this.TextToPass;
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Is this for windows forms? How do you implement this for WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines:
You don't have to add controls asynchronously. Add them in the GUI thread and every time create a new worker thread supplying it with the delegate from your control which will be called asynchronously (using BeginInvoke?) when the worker finished loading the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand why you've wrapped a UI operation in its own Task.. when it isn't chained to an async Task.

Anyway.. PictureBoxes have a LoadAsync method. Why make this harder than it needs to be?

```
private void ButtonClick()
{
    CustomControl.PersonResult newControl = new CustomControl.PersonResult();
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(newControl);
    newControl.PictureBox.WaitOnLoad = false;
    newControl.PictureBox.LoadAsync("http://url-here.com/image.jpg");
}
```